# Wordpress Theme Development: How to redirect templates the right way?

Tags: theme-development, templates, redirect, template-hierarchy

I'm developing a theme for WordPress. I have a doubt about templates redirect. For example, I have a theme that have the `front-page.php` template and I don't use the `index.php` template. What I should do it with index.php file? Delete it or redirect like:

index.php

```php
<?php

wp_safe_redirect('front-page.php');
exit();
```

The redirect affects the performance of the site? Should I left the template blank If I don't use it?

I always have this doubt about templates. If I don't use `archive.php` template for example, I should delete it or redirect to the template I use? I don't know what to do with the underscore theme files (the files I don't use).

Template Hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png

Underscores base theme: http://underscores.me/

Comment: looks good for index. Sure you could delete the other pages too.

Comment: Did  you mean I can delete the index.php of the theme? But here in the docs says that is a required file: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/

Comment: no, don't delete index.  delete other pages.  redirect or die on index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason to redirect `index.php`. Let's say you only have a Front Page, no blog or post types with archives. You would assign the Front Page in Settings -> Reading and WordPress will do the template redirect for you. At that point, nothing uses `index.php` and there's no need to redirect it.

Maybe you install a plugin which create a post type and, by default, uses `index.php` to display its posts. You'll want something to display instead of redirecting it otherwise you may spend time trying to figure out why the archive of this plugin is redirecting. Copy / Paste the `page.php` template and throw some baseline styles into it.

If you *do* have a post type archive or blog and want to keep the single posts but **do not** want an archive you can use the [`template_redirect` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) to redirect the request:

```
/**
 * Redirect Archive Pages
 *
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_redirects() {

    if( is_post_type_archive( 'foobar' ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_redirects' );
```

The tools are there if you really need them but since `index.php` is the default display for post type archives it's not something I would redirect but instead add some baseline styles to. You can always do more specific template overrides later if you need to.

Comment: Setting `has_archive` to `false` when registering the post type would be far simpler.

Comment: So, index.php is a required theme file as the theme handbook says, so I will put "<?php //silence is golden" like they do in their empty index.php and if Wordpress misredirect some page to index.php for example because of a plugin, I will use the hook you said: 'template_redirect', I think  It solves the problem.

Comment: If you're trying to use another template, you should be using the [`template_include` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include). My point is that you shouldn't be redirecting `index.php` at all in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Don't redirect in templates to other templates. That's not how templates work. Notice in your browser that you're never redirected to single.php or front-page.php or anything like that. If you do this then if you load a page that uses index.php your browser is going to redirect to `http://website.com/front-page.php` and you'll get a 404.

Templates are loaded with `include` (or `require`) in PHP by WordPress to render the page as part of a process involving many WordPress files. They are not a loaded directly, and they are not redirected to.

The first thing to note for your specific example is that index.php is a [required file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/release/required-theme-files/) for WordPress themes. So you can't delete it, and you shouldn't redirect from it. So if your front-page.php and index.php templates are the same, then you should be deleting front-page.php, not index.php.

You should start your theme with index.php, which should be the template for a generic list of posts. Then you start adding templates based on your design requirements, by referring to the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) and adding the ones you need.

However, let's say I have a custom post type whose archive template (eg. `archive-project.php`) needs to be the same as the taxonomy archive template for its taxonomy (eg. `taxonomy-project_category.php`). Both post type archives and taxonomy archives fall back to `archive.php`. The problem is that if you're already using that for regular posts, you can't create a single template for both types of page.

The simplest solution is to load one template into the other using `get_template_part()`. So `archive-project.php` could be your main template, and then `taxonomy-project_category.php` could look like this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'archive-project' ); ?>
```

Comment: The problem of delete the `front-page.php` template is that I use `page.php` template and I use it to display the pages of WordPress (in my case in specific, pages of WooCommerce). So If i delete it I don't get the front-page in the index.php but the page.php. I agree with you, things should start in `index.php` but sometimes, the template hierarchy is confusing to handle.

Comment: What have you got your front page set to in Settings > Reading? If you  want a list of posts you should not have it set to a page. Then index.php will load.

Comment: If I want to display a list of posts, I should use the `home.php`. I use the template for `front-page.php` because is a custom front page, isn't the right template?

Comment: Ok, so I’m not sure what index.php has to do with anything then? Since your brought it up in your question.

Comment: index.php is a obrigatory file you should put in the theme, read the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/what-is-a-theme/

Answer (score 1):

index.php can be `<?php //silent` here. Doesn’t matter at the theme level really. Unless you want to guarantee something before your `functions.php` file it’s obsolete in the theme directory. Just like anything else in php/html on apache servers anyway.